# Hi I'm having error when trying to install scipy1.7.2 with python3.10.0 pip21.2.4

Tags: python, pip, scipy

- My laptop runs macOS Monterey version 12.0.1, with Apple M1 Pro chip.
- I have tried downgrade python 3.9.7; 3,9,9, but this didn't work.
- Other packages such as numpy and pandas can be installed smoothly
- It says that ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1; not sure what causes that trouble
- I was able to install the SciPy with Homebrew
- Also this is my first time posting question on stack overflow, apology if anything is missing...
- Any help would be appreciated

```
jnl@Junnans-MacBook-Pro ~ % python3 -m pip install scipy==1.7.2
Collecting scipy==1.7.2
  Using cached scipy-1.7.2.tar.gz (36.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/f0/x0_4tx9n3yj3zvzdsb8l1p_m0000gn/T/tmpbu3u_sb8
       cwd: /private/var/folders/f0/x0_4tx9n3yj3zvzdsb8l1p_m0000gn/T/pip-install-y6nzhxiz/scipy_47a7ae3820d24fc49f3bdfc39df7a435
  Complete output (181 lines):
  setup.py:491: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/f0/x0_4tx9n3yj3zvzdsb8l1p_m0000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-twmv0w33'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
    warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
  Running from SciPy source directory.
  /private/var/folders/f0/x0_4tx9n3yj3zvzdsb8l1p_m0000gn/T/pip-install-y6nzhxiz/scipy_47a7ae3820d24fc49f3bdfc39df7a435/scipy/linalg/_generate_pyx.py:674: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
    from distutils.dep_util import newer
  /private/var/folders/f0/x0_4tx9n3yj3zvzdsb8l1p_m0000gn/T/pip-install-y6nzhxiz/scipy_47a7ae3820d24fc49f3bdfc39df7a435/scipy/special/_generate_pyx.py:1443: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
    from distutils.dep_util import newer
  Running scipy/linalg/_generate_pyx.py
  Running scipy/special/_generate_pyx.py
  Running scipy/stats/_generate_pyx.py
  Processing scipy/cluster/_vq.pyx
  Processing scipy/cluster/_optimal_leaf_ordering.pyx
  Processing scipy/cluster/_hierarchy.pyx
  /private/var/folders/f0/x0_4tx9n3yj3zvzdsb8l1p_m0000gn/T/pip-install-y6nzhxiz/scipy_47a7ae3820d24fc49f3bdfc39df7a435/tools/cythonize.py:62: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion
  Processing scipy/ndimage/src/_cytest.pyx
  Processing scipy/ndimage/src/_ni_label.pyx
  Processing scipy/linalg/cython_lapack.pyx
  Processing scipy/linalg/_matfuncs_sqrtm_triu.pyx
  Processing scipy/linalg/_solve_toeplitz.pyx
  Processing scipy/linalg/cython_blas.pyx
  Processing scipy/linalg/_decomp_update.pyx.in
  Processing scipy/optimize/_group_columns.pyx
  Processing scipy/optimize/_bglu_dense.pyx
  Processing scipy/optimize/_trlib/_trlib.pyx
  Processing scipy/optimize/_highs/cython/src/_highs_constants.pyx
  Processing scipy/optimize/_highs/cython/src/_highs_wrapper.pyx
  Processing scipy/optimize/_lsq/givens_elimination.pyx
  Processing scipy/optimize/cython_optimize/_zeros.pyx.in
  Processing scipy/io/matlab/mio_utils.pyx
  Processing scipy/io/matlab/streams.pyx
  Processing scipy/io/matlab/mio5_utils.pyx
  Processing scipy/_lib/_ccallback_c.pyx
  Processing scipy/_lib/_test_deprecation_def.pyx
  Processing scipy/_lib/_test_deprecation_call.pyx
  Processing scipy/_lib/messagestream.pyx
  Processing scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.pyx
  Processing scipy/special/cython_special.pyx
  Processing scipy/special/_ellip_harm_2.pyx
  Processing scipy/special/_comb.pyx
  Processing scipy/special/_test_round.pyx
  Processing scipy/special/_ufuncs.pyx
  Processing scipy/fftpack/convolve.pyx
  Processing scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx
  Processing scipy/interpolate/_bspl.pyx
  Processing scipy/interpolate/_ppoly.pyx
  Processing scipy/sparse/_csparsetools.pyx.in
  Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_shortest_path.pyx
  Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_traversal.pyx
  Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_flow.pyx
  Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_tools.pyx
  Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_matching.pyx
  Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_reordering.pyx
  Processing scipy/sparse/csgraph/_min_spanning_tree.pyx
  Processing scipy/spatial/ckdtree.pyx
  Processing scipy/spatial/_voronoi.pyx
  warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:9:8: Unreachable code
  warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:13:4: Unreachable code
  warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:21:8: Unreachable code
  warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:25:4: Unreachable code
  warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:33:8: Unreachable code
  warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:37:4: Unreachable code
  warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:45:8: Unreachable code
  warning: _cython_special_custom.pxi:49:4: Unreachable code
  Processing scipy/spatial/_hausdorff.pyx
  Processing scipy/spatial/qhull.pyx
  Processing scipy/spatial/transform/rotation.pyx
  Processing scipy/signal/_max_len_seq_inner.pyx
  Processing scipy/signal/_peak_finding_utils.pyx
  Processing scipy/signal/_upfirdn_apply.pyx
  Processing scipy/signal/_spectral.pyx
  Processing scipy/signal/_sosfilt.pyx
  Processing scipy/stats/_stats.pyx
  Processing scipy/stats/_qmc_cy.pyx
  Processing scipy/stats/_sobol.pyx
  Processing scipy/stats/biasedurn.pyx
  Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/beta_ufunc.pyx
  Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/nbinom_ufunc.pyx
  Processing scipy/stats/_boost/src/binom_ufunc.pyx
  Cythonizing sources
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  openblas_clapack_info:
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  flame_info:
    libraries flame not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  accelerate_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_3_10_info:
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_info:
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  lapack_info:
    libraries lapack not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  /private/var/folders/f0/x0_4tx9n3yj3zvzdsb8l1p_m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-w418801w/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  /private/var/folders/f0/x0_4tx9n3yj3zvzdsb8l1p_m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-w418801w/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "/private/var/folders/f0/x0_4tx9n3yj3zvzdsb8l1p_m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-w418801w/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 166, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      self.run_setup()
    File "/private/var/folders/f0/x0_4tx9n3yj3zvzdsb8l1p_m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-w418801w/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 258, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "/private/var/folders/f0/x0_4tx9n3yj3zvzdsb8l1p_m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-w418801w/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 150, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 631, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "setup.py", line 627, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "/private/var/folders/f0/x0_4tx9n3yj3zvzdsb8l1p_m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-w418801w/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "setup.py", line 529, in configuration
      raise NotFoundError(msg)
  numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No BLAS/LAPACK libraries found. Note: Accelerate is no longer supported.
  To build Scipy from sources, BLAS & LAPACK libraries need to be installed.
  See site.cfg.example in the Scipy source directory and
  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/index.html for details.
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/23/58c4f995475a2a97cb5f4a032aedaf881ad87cd976a7180c55118d105a1d/scipy-1.7.2.tar.gz#sha256=fa2dbabaaecdb502641b0b3c00dec05fb475ae48655c66da16c9ed24eda1e711 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/) (requires-python:>=3.7,<3.11). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/f0/x0_4tx9n3yj3zvzdsb8l1p_m0000gn/T/tmpbu3u_sb8 Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scipy==1.7.2 (from versions: 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 0.13.3, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 1.0.0b1, 1.0.0rc1, 1.0.0rc2, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0rc2, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0rc2, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0rc2, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.7.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for scipy==1.7.2
```

Comment: I think this question is directly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65745683/how-to-install-scipy-on-apple-silicon-arm-m1

Comment: And here is a relevant issue on the SciPy issue tracker: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13409

Comment: Thanks very much for directing me to these thread. Yea, I think they explain the cause of the issue. As a user w/o developer background, I reckon the best I can do is to wait till the release of 1.7.3. Thanks very much.