# Why does spaCy run slower in a difference conda environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spacy

I used JupyterLab to preprocess a larger set of text documents with spaCy. While there's overall no problem, I've noticed that there's a huge speed difference when I use different conda kernels / virtual environments. The difference is about 10x.

Both environments have the same version of spaCy and NumPy installed; also both using the same Python version (3.9.15).

```
numpy                   1.23.4          py39h14f4228_0
spacy                   3.3.1           py39h79cecc1_0
```

so I cannot tell where the speed difference might come from. Maybe it's from another package that spaCy requires?

I also converted the notebooks into .py scripts and running from the console, but the same results: In one virtual environment it runs about 10x slower.

Comment: Can you check what BLAS/LAPACK libraries are installed in each environment? Differences there might matter (though not usually a whole order of magnitude). E.g., [having `mkl` vs `netlib`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70241376/570918).

Comment: Both environments have `mkl 2021.4.0 h06a4308_64` installed, if case this clarifies things. I assume `mkl` when installing `numpy` or something. The "slow" environment I created just 2 days ago and I'm sure it didn't install it explicitly.

Comment: I looked through `conda list` again and noticed that `cupy` was not yet installed in the "slow" environment, and I indeed use a GPU. Now I see the same performance using either environment.

Answer (score 1):

The "slow" environment was missing `cupy`. After installing it, spaCy shows the same performance in both environments.