# How to maximize performance of spaCy on an M1 Mac (currently much slower than Intel)

Tags: python, spacy, apple-m1

I've observed that `nlp.pipe` is 30-40% slower on my almost brand new M1 Pro Macbook than on my old Macbook Pro from 2017. Most other functions are faster on the M1 by a similar margin, so this is not the performance I would expect.

For a benchmark, I'm running the following code (with scispacy):

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import re
import spacy
import time


with open(Path(os.path.expanduser('~')) / 'Downloads' / 'icd10cm-table and index-April 1 2023' / 'icd10cm-tabular-April 1 2023.xml') as f:
    content = f.read()
matches = re.findall(r'<desc>([^<]*)</desc>', content)

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_sci_lg')
start_time = time.time()
for x in nlp.pipe(matches):
    pass
print('%s seconds elapsed' % (time.time() - start_time))
```

My M1 Mac takes over 75 seconds to complete the task, while my 2017 Intel Mac can do it in 46 seconds.

I don't know whether `spacy` uses `numpy`, but I installed a fast version of `numpy` using ABarrier's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70240506/why-is-numpy-native-on-m1-max-greatly-slower-than-on-old-intel-i5). That made `numpy` faster, but made no difference for `spacy`. I'm assuming that somewhere there is an unoptimized binary being used, but I don't know how to figure out what it is.

---

Instructions to replicate my benchmark:

You can get the file I'm using [here (cdc.gov)](https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Publications/ICD10CM/April-1-2023-Update/icd10cm-table%20and%20index-April%201%202023.zip); it's a table of ICD-10 concepts in XML format. If you don't have scispacy or don't have the `en_core_sci_lg` model, create an environment and run

```
pip install scispacy
pip install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-scispacy/releases/v0.5.1/en_core_sci_lg-0.5.1.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the package `thinc-apple-ops`:

```
pip install thinc-apple-ops
```

Or through the `spacy` extra:

```
pip install 'spacy[apple]'
```

(The unoptimized package is `blis`. We'd like to be able to switch to a newer version of BLIS with M1 support, but there are still some open bugs.)

Comment: This worked to make spaCy fast (13 seconds from 75!), but it also force-overwrites numpy, which is a shame because my `conda install -c conda-forge numpy "libblas=*=*accelerate` version of numpy is twice as fast. I can overwrite that numpy by running the command again, and it doesn't prevent spaCy from working, at least on my trivial benchmark, but the fast numpy performance doesn't come back. Do you have any idea how I could have fast numpy and fast spaCy coexisting in the same environment?

Comment: If you have the dev requirements installed, you should be able compile it against a custom numpy install by using something like `pip install thinc-apple-ops --no-build-isolation --no-binary thinc-apple-ops`.