# Long creation time with conda env create -f environment.yml

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have the following `environment.yml` file. It is taking 1.5 hours to create this environment. How to improve (or debug) the creation time?

```
name: test_syn_spark_3_3_1
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.10
  - pandas=1.5
  - pip=23.0
  - pyarrow=11.0.0
  - pyspark=3.3.1
  - setuptools=65.0
  - pip:
      - azure-common==1.1.28
      - azure-core==1.26.1
      - azure-datalake-store==0.0.51
      - azure-identity==1.7.0
      - azure-mgmt-core==1.3.2
      - azure-mgmt-resource==21.2.1
      - azure-mgmt-storage==20.1.0
      - azure-storage-blob==12.16.0
      - azure-mgmt-authorization==2.0.0
      - azure-mgmt-keyvault==10.1.0
      - azure-storage-file-datalake==12.11.0
      - check-wheel-contents==0.4.0
      - pyarrowfs-adlgen2==0.2.4
      - wheel-filename==1.4.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Switch the channel order and use Mamba**. Specifically,  I note that `pyspark=3.3.1` is only available from Conda Forge, so the `conda-forge` channel should go first to avoid any `channel_priority: strict` masking issues. Mamba is faster, gives clearer error reporting, and the maintainers are very responsive.

**test_syn_spark_3_3_1.yaml**

```yaml
name: test_syn_spark_3_3_1
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
# rest the same...
```

Create with Mamba (or micromamba):

```
## install mamba if needed
## conda install -n base -c conda-forge mamba
mamba env create -n test_syn_spark_3_3_1 -f test_syn_spark_3_3_1.yaml
```

This runs in a few minutes on my machine, which is mostly downloading time.

---

#### Other Thoughts

1. I wouldn't ever impose a fixed constraint on `pip` or `setuptools` unless there is a specific bug you are avoiding. I'd probably at least loosen to use lower bounds.
2. Conda Forge is fully self-sufficient these days - I would not only drop `defaults`, but even insulate against any channel mixing with `nodefaults` directive.
3. I notice `defaults` channel prefers MKL for BLAS on x64 whereas Conda Forge defaults to OpenBLAS. So, you may want to explicitly declare your preference (e.g., `accelerate` on macOS arm64, `mkl` on Intel).

In summary, this is how I would write the YAML:

```yaml
name: test_syn_spark_3_3_1
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults    # insulate from user config
dependencies:
  ## Python Core
  - python=3.10
  - pip >=23.0
  - setuptool >=65.0

  ## BLAS
  ## adjust for hardware/preference
  - blas=*=mkl

  ## Conda Python pkgs
  - pandas=1.5
  - pyarrow=11.0.0
  - pyspark=3.3.1
  
  ## PyPI pkgs
  - pip:
    - azure-common==1.1.28
    - azure-core==1.26.1
    - azure-datalake-store==0.0.51
    - azure-identity==1.7.0
    - azure-mgmt-core==1.3.2
    - azure-mgmt-resource==21.2.1
    - azure-mgmt-storage==20.1.0
    - azure-storage-blob==12.16.0
    - azure-mgmt-authorization==2.0.0
    - azure-mgmt-keyvault==10.1.0
    - azure-storage-file-datalake==12.11.0
    - check-wheel-contents==0.4.0
    - pyarrowfs-adlgen2==0.2.4
    - wheel-filename==1.4.1
```

Comment: First time I heard about mamba. Is it compatible with conda?

Comment: It is a compiled reimplementation of Conda (plus some extras). Everything is still Conda environments, just a faster frontend. For DevOps stuff, there is also Micromamba, which is fully standalone tool for creating Conda environments.

Comment: How do we know which BLAS to use for Apple M2 Pro?

Comment: I use `accelerate` on my M1 (API is same for M2). There is a little benchmarking [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70240506/570918).