# Why pytorch is running slow in conda env

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, apple-silicon

I'm using a m1 pro macbook, and I installed pytoch directly on my machine using `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio` this command. Also I created a virtualized env(phthon 3.10) with conda and using the same install command.

When I run a very small training set the result differed significantly. The non-virtualized version resulted in 20s and virtualized version resulted in 40s.

First I thought maybe the Apple SIP has some effect on the execution of the conda env, so I disabled it. But it turned out that it made no difference.

So, what is causing training process in conda env so much slower?

Comment: Not enough info. What "installed...directly" means is unclear - macOS does not come with Python installed. Please provide a minimal example that others can recreate.  Also, please indicate whether your Conda installation is **osx-arm64** (native) or is **osx-64** (emulated). Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70240506/570918

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm using the intel version of anaconda, after reinstalling with the m1 version, the performance issue goes away.